# User Control, Shared Property, setting label text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I usually make user controls containing forms for adding and editing data for a particular table in my database. I then show or hide these controls as the user clicks "edit" buttons, etc. It's common practice (for me) to put properties in the code-behind, that are used for setting the ID of the item being edited, into a hidden label on the page, and of course leaving it blank for new items being inserted. I usually only use C#, however, this time around I have to use VB.NET.

So in C# I would do the following:

```
public static int EditID
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(lblEditID.Text);
    }
    set
    {
        lblEditID.Text = value;
    }
}
```

..and then when the user, say, clicks an "edit" link from a gridview, I would

```
//set the ID of the corresponding record, something like this:
MyUserControl.EditID = MyGridView.SelectedDataKey[0];
```

Cool. So now I need to do this in VB.NET, and here's my code:

```
Public Shared Property EditID As Integer
    Get
        Return Convert.ToInt32(lblEditID.Text)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        lblEditID.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

but I get a syntax error that says: "**Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.**", highlighting the `lblEditID` for both the getter and setter.

I can't find any other SO questions about this, and I have Google'd just about every permutation of keywords I can think of, so this must be something really stupid.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Yes I realize I could just use a Session variable instead of the label, but I would still like to know why this doesn't work and how I could make it work with a label.

Comment: Note: Switch Option Strict On when coding in VB, this won't fix your error but it will help avoid some pitfalls. When you switch it on you will see that you can't assign an integer to a String property

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I'll do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a `Shared` property for this. `lblEditID` is a label that exists in an instance of a WebForm class:- it can't exist until an instance of this class has been created, hence the error.

I don't really understand how the C# worked as this should be the same but I'm not a C# expert.

If you remove the Shared keyword it will work as you want I believe